# Is it a risk to post my varnish default.vcl file publicly?

Tags: varnish

Recently, I solved a problem in my server by adjusting the default.vcl file. The problem is with wordpress... Another person also have that problem and have asked whether i can show my default vcl file to him... is it safe to post it one that forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends highly what is inside your default.vcl file. If it is simple and doesn't reveal too much detailed information about your environment for crackers to use (like open ports other than 80 and 443 or operating system usernames)  I'd say it is safe to post it to a forum.